# Elevate & impersonate User in C#

Tags: c#, process, registry, impersonation, elevated-privileges

We have some clients, where the user don't have admin privileges. But sometimes, they need to import a reg file into their registry. Now i'm trying to create a application, which can do that ...

But how can i import a reg file? I can start the process with other credentials:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\regedit.exe";
p.StartInfo.UserName = "domainadmin";
p.StartInfo.Password = ConvertToSecureString("password");
p.StartInfo.Domain = "domain";
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Windows\";

p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();
```

**Error: The requested Operation requires elevation**

But how can i elevate and impersonate it? I can only elevate it with

```
p.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
```

But then, i can't use other credentials, because i need to set `p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute` to `true`. Then i tried to [impersonate](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/joncole/2009/09/21/impersonation-code-in-c/) first and the use `p.StartInfo.Verb = "runas"` but this doesn't work either.

**Error: The operation was canceled by the user**

Next try: Impersonate and directly access the registry. But without admin rights, i cant do this either ...

Comment: "But sometimes, they need to import a reg file into their registry" - so why isn't the installer for this application setting appropriate permissions on the part of the registry which this import needs to change? That's the more obvious route to go down.

Comment: Hm ... never thought about that possibility. It's about CAD software. U need to modify the registry, to connect to different databases. I employee A works today in the BMW project, he needs settings for BMW. If he has tomorrow something to do in the VW project, he needs other settings and a new connections to an other database.